# Powershell ProgramFiles directory script

Tags: c#, powershell

The script to run is this.

```
string script = "powershell -executionpolicy unrestricted C:\Program Files (x86)\TEST\test.ps1"
```

But the error says (x86) is not ~

How to I solve this problem?

Comment: Use `'` for the path because it has space in it?

Comment: I've search other answer telling me to use &'C:\Program Files (x86)\TEST\test.ps1' but give error saying AmpersandNotAllowed use "" etc

Comment: `string script = "powershell -executionpolicy unrestricted -file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\TEST\test.ps1'"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution was:

```
string script = "powershell -executionpolicy unrestricted -file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\TEST\test.ps1'"
```